# Intellij launcher doesn't work on unity?

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, ubuntu-unity

Under `/usr/share/applications` I created:

`intellij.desktop`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/path/To/idea.sh"
Name[en_US]=Intellij
Name=Intellij
Icon=/path/to/intellij.png
```

Then I drag it to the Unity launcher bar. I click it, but nothing happens. How can I make it work?

`JAVA_HOME` is set correctly, other Java apps (like Eclipse) work and click `idea.sh`.

---

My configuration:

- Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit (Desktop)
- Oracle JDK 1.7
- IntelliJ Community 12

Comment: Is there a dangling " at the end of the Exec line? Also, you're probably better served at askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

You can use "*tools*" > "*create desktop entry*", in IntelliJ itself.

Comment: Came across this. I might add: after the above you can "Lock to Launcher" as you do normally. The above simply enables it.

Comment: Note: if you run the IDE from the "idea.sh" script and then right click on the icon and "Lock to Launcher" before you use "create desktop entry", a bad ~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-idea-ce.desktop "desktop entry" will be created. Since the local one overrides the one in /usr/share/applications (where the entry is placed if you say create for all users), it needs to be deleted for the icon to ever work correctly.

Comment: "Lock to launcher" after you run idea.sh from the terminal won't work: it will create a desktop entry with the full Java invocation: for some reason that doesn't work.  Using the "Configuration > Create desktop launcher" from the 'splash screen' does create the right desktop entry; however, it does *not* sets correctly the 'x' permissions (whether for all users or just for the given user): you will have to run a `chmod a+x jetbrains-idea.desktop` to make it work.  BTW - am I the only one to HATE the fact that now Unity does not let you right-click edit the launcher icons?

Comment: @JamesCaccese's comment helped resolve my issue. But in my computer, I deleted `~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-idea.desktop` file, since there wasn't a `jetbrains-idea-ce.desktop` file.

Comment: Amazing! Love Idea because they care even for this small things! Works well on 14.10

Comment: Does not work in Ubuntu 21.04. Creates the .desktop file but the launcher icon does not appear.

Comment: I didn't have a Tools menu, and had to click on the "settings cog" to access this option.

Answer (score 25):

1. Open a terminal, in **/path/idea/bin** folder
2. Start IntelliJ with **./idea.sh**
3. **Tools** -> **Generate Desktop Entry**
4. Close IntelliJ
5. In the terminal, start nautilus as admin (**gksudo nautilus**)
6. Go to **/usr/share/applications**
7. Drag the new icon for IntelliJ to your launcher

Comment: Step 3 should have generated a shortcut on Desktop? I can't see it, instead I have a launcher from search with Win key (I don't know if it was there previously before Generating it from Idea. So, at step 7 I don't have anything to drag in applications folder.
Anyway, I've search it once, lock it to Launcher and now it's as I was expected :) Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

event with create desktop entry there still an error, because the launcher is not reading JDK_HOME configuration.

so after creating the desktop entry , right click on the launcher and select properties
then add bash -i before double quote in command input text
exp :command [ bash -i " /home/me/ides/idea/bin/idea.sh" %f  ]

Comment: this was my problem, thanks a lot!!
I use to change my java version and i couldn't start idea by clicking the icon

Answer (score 11):

For starting IntelliJ IDEA from launcher

1. Create an idea.desktop file and include the following in it.

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Name=IntelliJ IDEA
    Comment=IntelliJ IDEA IDE
    Exec=/{installation directory}/idea-IC-129.713/bin/idea.sh
    Icon=/{installation directory}/idea-IC-129.713/bin/idea.png
    Terminal=false
    StartupNotify=true
    Type=Application
    Categories=Development;IDE;
```

2. Add permission file to be executable (right click on file in permissions tab and check the execute permission) [or `sudo chmod +x idea.desktop`]

3. Copy that file to `/usr/share/applications` (in the command line, do `sudo cp idea.desktop /usr/share/applications`)

 4. Copy that file to `~/.local/share/applications` (command line, `sudo cp idea.desktop ~/.local/share/applications`)

Now check in dash.

Answer (score 6):

I normally just create a runner under the normal menu (right click on start menu and choose edit) that points to something like `bash -i ~/bin/idea/bin/idea.sh`

I use `bash -i` to have it read .bashrc where I have JAVA_HOME set up correctly.
That works like any other program.

bin/idea is always a link to the latest version so I never have to recreate this start menu item.

Comment: Start menu? Doesn't sound like you're using Unity.

Answer (score 5):

I just came across this and I want to add to the answer something for people who may need it.

> You can use "tools" > "create desktop entry", in IntelliJ

like in this picture:
[image]
if you open intellij the first time you should create a new project to do this. it took me a while to figure that out

Answer (score 4):

For new installation, create desktop entry from: `Tools > Create Desktop Entry`

If you are upgrading IntelliJ to a new version do the following:

```bash
ll ~/.local/share/applications | grep idea
```

You should see these two files

```bash
-rw------- 1 user user  315 Mar 28 17:06 jetbrains-idea-ce.desktop
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  311 Mar 28 17:06 jetbrains-idea.desktop
```

Open both files and update newly installed IntelliJ path in both of them

```bash
[Desktop Entry]
  Version=1.0
  Type=Application
  Name=IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
  Icon=/home/user/Downloads/idea-IU-181.4203.550/bin/idea.png
  Exec="/home/user/Downloads/idea-IU-181.4203.550/bin/idea.sh" %f
  Comment=The Drive to Develop
  Categories=Development;IDE;
  Terminal=false
  StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea-ce
```

Answer (score 2):

On my machine running Ubuntu 17.10 and having Intellij installed using snap i couldn't find any **Create Desktop Entry** option.

As it turned out, i had to copy the `.desktop` file from `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications` to `.local/share/applications`.

Answer (score 1):

create file jetbrains-datagrip.desktop

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/jetbrains-datagrip.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=DataGrip
Icon=/home/gilcierweb/DataGrip/bin/product.png
Exec="/home/gilcierweb/DataGrip/bin/datagrip.sh" %f
Comment=Develop with pleasure!
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-datagrip
```

Answer (score 1):

Just posting in case some other people come across this issue.

For me all I had to do right click the entry and go to properties and in the `Application` tab under `Work path` I put the full path to the bin folder.

For example `/home/teodorvecerdi/Development/idea-IU-172.3317.76/bin/`.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

1. `cd /bin`
2. `ln -s <path to idea.sh> idea` - now it is available in the dash under "idea"
3. open **dash**, type **idea** and **start IntelliJ**
4. right **click on the icon in the sidebar** and **add it to the starter**

Answer (score 0):

In order to have just one IntelliJ icon on the Launcher you need to add following line to your idea .desktop file:

```
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea
```

My working sample idea.desktop file looks like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Idea13
Icon=/usr/local/bin/idea13/bin/idea.png
Exec=/usr/local/bin/idea13/bin/idea.sh
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Ubuntu users,**

This can be due to a change to the location of `idea.sh` file.

As a first step, you can just run the `idea.sh` file and make sure it's working as expected.

In the application launcher it typically has a ".desktop" file extension and contains information about the application(it's name, icon, command to run the application, and other metadata).

In Ubuntu operating system, the location `~/.local/share/applications` typically points to a directory in a user's home folder that contains desktop application launchers or shortcuts. You should find the `.desktop` file for `JIdea` in the same location.

Check and confirm the paths for the `Exec` is correct (and `Icon` if it's applicable). If it's not correct it and that should do the trick.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition
Icon=/home/user/Software/ideaIU-2020.3/idea-IU-203/bin/idea.svg
Exec="/home/user/Software/ideaIU-2020.3/idea-IU-203/bin/idea.sh" %f
Comment=Capable and Ergonomic IDE for JVM
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea
StartupNotify=true
```

If this file is not there, you can create a fresh one as well. Just copy the above content and make sure the paths are correct